# How to get the params from javascript url

Tags: javascript

If my script having a param, how can we read the id param inside the javascript script
 `<script src="https://test.com/test.js?id=123"></script>`
I have tried getting the base html URL from window.location but i am looking for reading params from js url

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as follows:

```js
const scriptTag = document.getElementById('my-script-tag');
const scriptUrl = scriptTag.getAttribute('src');
alert(scriptUrl);
```

```html
<script id="my-script-tag" src="https://some.js.url?some=parameter">
</script>
```

Comment: I would like to know any usage of this stuff. When I have the script tag in my file, why should I parse my own file instead of using the values which I already know?

Comment: I don't really know what the usecase of this is, I just answered the question :)

Comment: Usage can be somewhere where the same js is used in multiple places. Instead of hosting the multiple js with the hardcoded value.

Comment: You cannot insert the same script two times. If you insert the script it is available from all other sources

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) and an [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) object to parse it for you.

```
<script src="https://test.com/test.js?id=123">
  const curScriptElement = document.currentScript;
  const url = new URL(curScriptElement.src);
  const params = url.searchParams;
  const id = params.get('id')
</script>
```